# In SQL, how do I select * from a table, but when multiple rows have the same field, select only the ones where another field B is MAX?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

For example, I have a Table

| Id | CarPartId | CarPartPrice | Metadata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | spanner | 580 | Some other data |
| 2 | spanner | 570 | Some other data 2 |
| 3 | wheel | 423 | Some other data |
| 4 | window | 234 | Some other data |
| 5 | engine | 568 | Some other data 1 |
| 6 | engine | 423 | Some other data 2 |

Notice that when I do a SELCT * FROM this table, I would get two rows of CarPartId, but what I really want is to get the CarPartId row whereby the CarPartPrice is the highest, along with other rows from the table.

How do I achieve this? For example, my query should return this

| Id | CarPartId | CarPartPrice | Metadata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | spanner | 580 | Some other data |
| 3 | wheel | 423 | Some other data |
| 4 | window | 234 | Some other data |
| 5 | engine | 568 | Some other data 1 |

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Do you mean you want rows sorted by `CarPartPrice`? Or you want one row with highest price?

Comment: @Shireen I do not want rows sorted by `CarPartPrice` , I simply want all the rows, but if there are multiple rows with the same `CarPartId` , I only want the rows with the highest `CarPartPrice`

Comment: check my answer. let me know if it works.

Comment: Use window functions like `row_number()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), PARTITION by another column in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-partition-by-another-column-in-mys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * from table INNER JOIN
  (SELECT CarPartId, MAX(CarPartPrice) as MaxPrice
    FROM table GROUP BY CarPartId
  ) grouptable
ON table.CarPartId = grouptable.CarPartId
AND table.CarPartPrice = grouptable.MaxPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "along with other rows from the table" I understand you want to see all the rows. So below will show all data but sorted with highest CarPartPrice at the top row:

```
Select * From this table
Order by CarPartPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a nested query.

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM Table t1
 WHERE t1.CarPartPrice = ( SELECT MAX(t2.CarPartPrice)
                             FROM Table t2
                         GROUP BY t2.CarPartId
                           HAVING t2.CarPartId = t1.CarPartId)
```

The nested query will give you the highest CarPartPrice per Id.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is select max()

```
SELECT CarPartId, MAX(CarPartPrice)
FROM this table 
GROUP BY CarPartId
```